# Definition of real-valued lower semicontinuous function on compact interval of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$ with $a<b$. Let $f\colon [a, b] \to \mathbb R$. Then $f$ is lower semicontinuous on $[a, b]$ provided that $\forall x \in [a, b]$, $f(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{[a, b] \ni y \to x} f(y)$.

I have been struggling with what it means for us to have for $x \in [a, b]$, $f(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{[a, b] \ni y \to x} f(y)$. In class, my teacher stated that $\liminf\limits_{[a, b] \ni y \to x} f(y) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\inf\{f(y) \mid y \in [x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon] \setminus \{x\}\} = \sup\limits_{\epsilon>0}\{\inf\{f(y) \mid y \in [x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon]\setminus \{x\}\}\}.$

I have been trying to think up what it means for $f(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{[a, b] \ni y \to x} f(y)$ using the definition of $\liminf$ which involves the limit as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. Ideally, I would like this: $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that, $\forall y \in [a, b]$, $0<|x-y|<\delta \implies f(x)-\epsilon<f(y)$. I have seen something very similar to this on wikipedia, but instead of $f(x)-\epsilon<f(y)$ they say $f(x)-\epsilon \leq f(y)$. I am not sure, but I think the $\leq$ comes from the definition of $\liminf$ which takes the $\sup$ over all $\epsilon>0$.

I wish I could explain myself better, but I am very confused on what it means for $f(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{[a, b] \ni y \to x} f(y)$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit: Could anyone also explain why in the definition of $\liminf$ my teacher looks at closed balls about $x$ that do not contain $x$. I think I understand why we look at punctured balls, but do they need to be closed? I would think open is fine.

Comment: OK, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: Can someone give me a definition of what it means for $f(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{[a, b] \ni y \to x} f(y)$ using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Comment: "Ideally, I would like …" is exactly it. Whether you use $> f(x) - \epsilon$ or $\geqslant f(x) - \epsilon$ is irrelevant. Since $\epsilon$ is universally quantified, the two are equivalent. [Clearly $f(y) > f(x) - \epsilon$ implies $f(y) \geqslant f(x) - \epsilon$. On the other hand, $f(y) \geqslant f(x) - \epsilon/2$ implies $f(y) > f(x) - \epsilon$.]

Comment: And yes, whether one takes closed or open balls in the definition of $\liminf$ is also irrelevant. Every open ball is contained in the closed ball with the same radius, and it contains the closed balls with smaller radius.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. Could you also explain how we get the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition from the definitions I've been given. I'm also thinking now that we don't necessarily need punctured balls, if the function is defined at that point. Is this true? Thanks so much for your help!